# Add facebook icons to slider revolitution

Tags: wordpress, slider

I want to add facebook icon,instagram icon, and whatsapp icon and link them in slider revolution,can anyone explain it to me how to link them thank you!
And in mobile mode it doesnt show full width.. i changed settings but still doesnt show

```
<i class="fa-icon-facebook-square"></i> 
<i class=fa-icon-facebook-square"></i><a href"#">
```

Comment: Can u show me an example thank you !

Comment: okay i will try..

Comment: im tryin  this 

but nothing happens 

<i class="fa-icon-facebook-square"><a href="https://google.com"></i>

Comment: it must be <a href="facebook"><i class="fa-icon-facebook-square"></i> 
but it links know  mywebsite/facebook.com and opened a not found page! how to make to load direct facebook

Comment: Which icon library you can you...

Comment: You can see this link https://www.w3schools.com/icons/icons_reference.asp

Answer (score 0):

1.First you need to select the slide where you need to add facebook,Instagram and WhatsUp icon.
2. Secondly you need to select object library.
3.Thirdly you need to type(facebook or Instagram or WhatsUp ) in the search box.than search result will show your desired icon.Just click on the icon that you need[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijSPG.png)